# clear input after search

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a search box on my site.  The search works well.  I'd like the search field to clear after you submit a search.  I have it working to clear onclick but the onsubmit doesn't work.  It is definitely submitting a search because I can see the results.

**js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clearDefault(el) {
if (el.defaultValue==el.value) el.value = ""
}
function clearText(thefield){
if (thefield.defaultValue==thefield.value)
thefield.value = ""
}
</script>
```

**view**

```
<%= form_tag guidelines_path, :class => 'navbar-search pull-right', :onSubmit=>"clearText(this)",:method => :get do %>  

<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'search-query', :placeholder=>"Search", :ONFOCUS=>"clearDefault(this)" %> <% end %
```

>

Answer (score 0):

Th `onsubmit` isn't an event of a text field but rather the form it belongs to. If you move your `onsubmit` attribute to the form, it should clear it.

Comment: you must be right but it still isn't working - have edited above to reflect the change

Comment: sorry I don't know what you mean to post what it looks like?

Comment: Two things: 1. you're not passing anything into the `clearText` function when you're calling it from your `onsubmit` and 2. you're calling it as `cleartext` instead of `clearText`

Comment: That's ok, do you understand what you need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pass the field as a parameter, why not just fetch the field by it's class? So using jquery:

```
function clearText(){
    search = $('.search-query');
    if (search.defaultValue==search.value)
    search.value = ""
}
```

If you can't use jQuery for some reason you could try and assign the form field an ID and use document.getElementById() instead?